# why close ups are too wide

Tags: troubleshooting, distortion

I have been taking close up pictures for a while with no problem.  I think I may have done something with the settings, because all of a sudden my closeups are distorted (wide).  I have a sony cyber shot.  I've gone through all the settings, but just can't figure out what I did.
Help please.

Comment: could you post some 'before and after' shots?

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you mean by "wide" or better still, post a sample image?

Comment: Is there a factory reset option? The manual may be of help.

Comment: i'm not sure how to post a pic here

Comment: @donna you can edit your post and then press the little rectangle with a landscape on it, the one to the right of the curly brackets {}, then select the picture you want to show and upload it, then repeat the process for as many pictures you want to upload, in this case I think just 2.

Comment: She can't post pics until she has 11 reputation. I'm voting the post up in good faith.

Answer (score 3):

Depending of the **focal length** of the lens e.g. 28mm, 55mm, 100mm etc. images can look distorted. As the sample below shows that an image taken with a wider angle lens with a same crop may look wider.

So a wide angle lens from a close range widens, while a longer does not.

The left is taken with a 28mm lens and the right with a 70mm lens.

I think the zoom factor of your *sony cyber shot* causes a close up might look wider. Perhaps you turned digital/software zoom on or off?

[image: differences]

*Left is taken with a 28mm lens, the right with 80mm, the nose is clearly wider on the left*

Try to **take more distance** and **zoom in more** to get the **same crop**.